# A way out of getting liability insurance for temporary freelancing?

Tags: insurance

So I am currently switching jobs and the small company I work at might need me to do a little consulting/freelancing for them while they find someone to replace me.

I am not really scared of them trying to sue me since I know them all on a personal level but I would still like to cover my back.

Is there some type of legal document I could have them sign saying basically if I write bad code they can't sue me? I am based in the USA.

I would rather not get insurance since this would be something that is temporary and would only be like 20 hours of work.

Comment: " if I write bad code they can't sue me" ... don't write bad code?

Comment: Why do you think they would sue you if you had a bug in your code? What are you coding? If it's for some military/medical application (so someone's life is on the line), then you're definitely (1) going to need to meet some standards and have the code pass a spec by an authority and (2) going to need liability insurance. If it could lose someone copious amounts of money, then that code better be tested thoroughly. In both cases, this shouldn't just fall on you, it probably would be a good idea to discuss who is responsible for testing the code. But I'm not a lawyer, perhaps you should ask one.

Comment: Have you considered just letting your current contract (perhaps modified to 0-hours) run on for a bit? It's not that weird to have two employers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely there is. You simply (ha!) need to get them to agree to add the following clause, or some variation thereof, to whatever written agreement you make with them.

> [The company] *agrees to indemnify and hold* [you] *not accountable for any loss or damage that occurs from their work, whether directly, indirectly or otherwise.*

Now, the tricky part of that is that they may choose not to agree. At that point you'll want to get liability insurance. There are [no end](https://www.hiscox.com/small-business-insurance/professional-business-insurance/it-insurance) of [potential suppliers](https://generalliabilityinsure.com/small-business/software-developer-insurance.html) and [the cost](https://www.techinsurance.com/professions/software-development?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=4df6f091d7e58e93ffdc3bbc5e76cb4d41aefb8e-1619649188-0-AesSeA1Ug0FH6W2RjUtqhJixbwo3NOLJ9zi9zf6CQPikuF0TjwBciKSaFjm5tkjIHjTP1FeEJ-nrGtjbvwLRFSWSVyjzwdQnL2hpOukZSlk4MqEwGAGLyS3GgeP_42tHcz2t7oInSDZufmnaR9VLqK6e3LY9Sm02TQufSZo30lRV9vLmbj4-Uo8x55lzBd8a9Ei92mbN-Vylf-lyvDM1JeDkC6wUx72RvhFgDSMrA8hNrMt2I0lOIWWV-gDHwmEHgPfBVd5TkClTH06uZjac6Ihe7O-uKyvp_oM5agJLFOpXsZ6uo3_LBzU4_AyFB1sCXnwENXUmY4OnS3Dr0xb14nVqweNC-C3u83KbPOgGBKG7c4YDpH0a6Xzgg0GaM9cLyAymLM-_SRdVQgZ9IotzJM7CPCcnGm2o8SNbtTrVyRxE5q32R_rN5Rga1qJ4hRAYxPDVJzZxOOm95cKQsH9nWW78U2wyh3ODwedWRNkF9lwD0ISHYLAJqM2ffalyt2A7Z261k1RdozayN9qIjJv8jKmKLQz8rY0Y1GdyaG6sedl_SZNxItxn5esqSSTEKH640bIeKNNipezkUhMa6yZxGr-bQCvk5t4d0Lz_sfkj6uaXq5N7W9-ZIxnYGAc8rFDLy1zmHUnN1xEjvDV5UwZb6mk), unless you're developing military or medical software, is likely to be in the tens of dollars for more cover than you could ever theoretically need.

Answer (score -1):

Consult with an attorney.  We're not attorneys here.

Comment: Right but there could always be someone who has had to deal with something similar here ;)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.